# Google search results show the source code

Tags: seo

I made a mistake when I helped a friend to set up her website. I forgot to upload robots.txt before I sent some text code onto the server to test the server. When she google her url in google, she can see the source code as a first result.

I now uploaded a robots.txt onto the server, but the old source code is still there although I have changed the code totally.

Can I fix this problem now?

Thanks

Comment: this is a web development related issue. I believe some basic robots.txt tips and knowledge is important for new web designers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time Google (or any other search engine) crawls your website, it'll see the robots.txt file and reindex (or remove) the site accordingly. If you absolutely must remove the site now, go to http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734.